# how to make clickable points in achartengine?

Tags: java, android, graph, achartengine

Hi im using AChartEngine to display progress in my app. I basically copied the `XYChartBuilder` except changed it to take a users data. However, I am not sure how to make the points clickable like they are in the embedded graph demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code for the demo [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list).

Once downloaded, please take a look at the class you mentioned and you will see the APIs to use for making points clickable.

Regards,

Dan